# Is it possible to create a software RAID 10 using SAN LUN's presented to server on 4 paths?

Tags: linux, raid, performance, configuration, filesystems

Is it possible to create a software RAID 10 using SAN LUN's presented to server on 4 paths?

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with 64 GB of RAM

Target is to achieve better I/O, storage and network teams have done all that is possible from their end to provide the best I/O's possible.

and I believe if we can do software RAID 10 using SAN LUN's presented on the server with additional SAN LUN's we should be able to achieve better performance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a software RAID 10 using SAN LUN's presented
>   to server on 4 paths?

Yes, the LUNs are just presented as regular block devices, that said why wouldn't you do this on the SAN array side anyway? that's the way everyone else does it - it saves 50% of bandwidth on writes for a start and is a lot easier to setup and manage.

Comment: You are right, it's already done at SAN level, we are thinking of software raid over it as we are not getting the required I/O's for read & write on the server. So I believe doing this will help us increase the performance. Let me know if you feel otherwise.

Comment: It depends on your SAN array, you could easily end up reducing your performance, it will be twice the write effort across the board of course.

Comment: right now we are getting a speed of 450 MB per second and that is not enough, we need to cross at lease 550 MB per second or 600 MB per second would be awesome!

Comment: Well yes, but maybe your array just can't do that - what is it?

Comment: EMC VNXe3200 Hybrid Storage

Comment: Ok, that's an ALUA-based system - the only way is to try it and see if you see enough performance benefit to justify the extra load sorry.

Comment: Are you sure it's your SAN LUNs that are slow?  What IO bandwidth do you get if you `dd` directly to/from the raw disk device?  Just be aware that writing to the raw device will corrupt anything on it. And if the LUNs are already redundant RAID devices presented by the SAN controller, you can probably just use RAID-0 on the server(s) for even more speed, but that will impact your availability. Even a 4+2 RAID-6 array on redundant-controller SAN devices doesn't have 100.00000% availability.